# How to indicate high wicks of more than 10%

Tags: pine-script-v4

This is my code, but it's not working, I don't understand why!!
Thanks for your help.
Peio

```
//@version=4
condition = high  close
wickPercentage = (high - close) * 100 / close 
if wickPercentage > 10
    plotValue =  wickPercentage >10 ? wickPercentage : na
plot(wickPercentage ? close : na, color=color.rgb(76, 134, 175), style=plot.style_columns)
```

All candles are displayed on the chart, minus the candles without a high wick.
And I would like to indicate that candles with a high wick above 10%

Answer (score 0):

The value of `wickPercentage` is always less than 10

Use `plotchar` as [debug method](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/writing/Debugging.html)

[image: Use DataWindows]

Something like this:

```
//@version=4
study("wickPercentage", overlay = true)

wickPercentage = (high - close) * 100 / close
plot(wickPercentage > 10 ? close : na, color=color.rgb(76, 134, 175), style=plot.style_columns)
//<debug>
plotchar(wickPercentage)
```